# WFFM No Data On Form Reports Page or Export

Tags: wffm

We are not able to retrieve any data after submission of a newly created form. The *Form Reports* page is completely void of any data in both the *Summary* and *Detailed Reports* tab. Exporting to Excel and XML also return nothing. There are no errors in the console on the *Form Reports* page.

There are no errors in the log file upon submission, no errors in the browser console, and the `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` is on the main layout.

Forms data provider is this:

`<formsDataProvider ref="/sitecore/wffm/analytics/analyticsFormsDataProvider"/>`

Versions:

**Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221)**

**Web Forms for Marketers 8.2.rev. 170518**

Any thoughts on how I can fix this or at least debug it further?

Comment: Did you check the database? Is there any data in there? What do your logs say when submitting a form?

Comment: I am not very familiar with WFFM so I wouldn't know what tables to look at. Also there as I mentioned above there are no errors in the logs for this. The form actually executes the save action and sends emails to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to simple user error.

- Once the form was published live to our CD server form submissions started showing up in the Form Reports view
- Learned that there is a delay between submission of form data and when it shows up in the Form Reports view due to the Session Time Out configuration. User data is note flushed to xDB until the active session has ended. In our case this was set to 60 minutes.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted N.Oliver, I had put about checking 'Session Time Out configuration' - point 5 above.

Answer (score 1):

> Update

Actually just checking your version numbers, it looks like your using the wrong version of WFFM for your version of Sitecore.

Unless I’m mistaken your Sitecore Version is 8.2 update 2 but you using WFFM for Sitecore 8.2 update 4. Can you double check this?

Here is what I’d do to debug this.

**Debugging data storage**

First check if your data is being stored correctly:

1) So first thing to check is that you have run the wffm_analytics.sql script to create the database tables correctly

2) submit a form and check the analytics database tables (in SQL server) to see if the data has saved correctly

3) check the Sitecore logs for any WFFM related errors

4) under the ‘submit’ section on your form in content editor check the ‘Save form data to storage’ checkbox is enabled. Try unchecking it, saving and checking again and saving to be sure.

5) check your session end timeout is firing. If it is set to quite a long time then perhaps reduce it to test and see if that causes data to be stored.

**Debugging reports**

So if the above proves there is data being stored in the db but it is just not being shown:

1) open the network console in your browser and check there are no 404 or 500 errors being thrown. IoC containers can cause issues like this. There is more info on this here:
https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/07/27/Simple-Injector-and-WFFM-Controller-Injection-Woes/

2) check the console in your browser for JavaScript errors. You may have missing files or something blocking the JavaScript executing.

Failing all of this double-check you have followed all of the steps in the deployment guide for WFFM 8.2 and if so perhaps spin up a new Sitecore 8.2 instance with SIM and install WFFM and see if it all works ok as it could be one of your customisation causing any issues:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers/82/Web_Forms_For_Marketers_82_Update4.aspx